# Cannot exchange short-lived token to long-lived token by instagram API

Tags: access-token, instagram-api

I should show the snapshot to you.
[Unsupported request - method type:get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO3rw.jpg)

Even the official documentation said that we can only use get to exchange token to long-lived token,
I still tried the post method to experiment, it also failed.

More information:
I passed the validation about instagram_graph_user_profile and instagram_graph_user_media,
but I am still facing the problem like the snapshot.

If I added this user to our testing account, this problem has never shown again,
I'm really frustrated about this.

Our website is an easy application,
we use LAMP structure to build our website,
please help me to solve this out :(
I can give more information if you need :)

Comment: FYI: Exchange to long-lived token is : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/long-lived-access-tokens/